# Django - Does user have to stay on website after pressing "Submit" button in form - for POST request to be processed?

Tags: django, post, django-models, django-views, http-post

I have a form that lets a user upload a csv file and has a submit button. Does the user need to stay on the webpage after pressing the submit button, "while page is reloading", in order to ensure that rows from the csv are added to the database? Or can user immediately leave the page after pressing submit button, and the rows from csv will still be added to database?

Here is my views.py file:

```
import pandas as pd
from .models import Contact

def upload_contacts(request):
    template = "contact_upload.html"

    prompt = {
        'order': 'Order of the CSV should be first_name, last_name'
    }

    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, template, prompt)


    your_file = request.FILES['file']

    df = pd.read_csv(your_file)

    if your_file.name.endswith('.csv'):

        for index, row in df.iterrows():

            created = Contact.objects.update_or_create(
                first_name = row[0],
                last_name = row[1]
            )

    else:
        messages.error(request, 'This is not a CSV file, please try another file.')

    context = {}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: The time between clicking the submit button, and seeing the resulting 'success page' load is composed of two parts that are invisible to the user. The first part is the browser sending the HTTP POST request to the server. The second part is the browser waiting for, then receiving, then loading the result. The first part is probably over quite quickly, and after that, the browser window can be safely closed. However, generally the user has no way of knowing exactly when that is.

Comment: The two parts that you explained are invisible to user makes sense. I'm sure there are a lot of factors that influence timing for this. But I'd like industry professional opinion on an estimate on how long the first part "the browser sending the HTTP POST request to the server" takes for say a 2mb csv or xlsx file. Let's assume we are using a standard paid Heroku server. What do you define as part 1 finishing quickly? 0.1s, 1s, 20s, 1min, 2min?

Comment: I'm trying to weight this basic upload implementation - versus learning / having to implement something that background tasks this upload such as using celery

Comment: hi, you can use jQuery submit function, inside an ajax function (again jQuery). so inside ajax you could provide a success function to make sure the data has been sent and was acceptable. take control of the form submission

Comment: You could upload via some javascript on the page as @MahdiFirouzjah suggests. Re: your question about how long it would take, that would depend entirely on network speed. If your users are all likely to have fast internet connections, then you could make a guess about this. It's unclear what problem you are trying to solve and why you are asking the question though.